# Changing LXQT Screen Resolution permanently in LUbuntu

Tags: lubuntu, display-resolution, lxqt

I'm using **Tinker** Board with Lubuntu 16.04.2, I'm able to change to screen resolution but it reverts back after restarting
`<br>` I've been researching for a while and all I see is how to change it in lxde, i tried browsing the config files located at `/etc/lxqt/..` but there no such thing there on how to change the resolution, all I see is the panel setting etc..

 Can anyone help me on this thankss

Comment: On bad device so can't post answer, but you need to set up a login script that uses xrandr. Search the site for that and you'll find how to do it.

Comment: "I'm able to change to screen resolution" and how is it you do that ?

Comment: @Panther on the Preferences>LXQt settings>Monitor settings

Comment: @OrganicMarble thanks able to make it change just before entering desktop by using "xrandr --output HDMI-1 --mode 1-24x768" on /etc/profile , I know this is not practical but it works so im fine with it, thanks

Comment: Glad it worked for you!

Comment: @GilbertMendoza thanks this works. its more of a brute changing of res every time it boots rather than setting it in lxqt which seems to be lacking documentation

Comment: @IshanSrivastava, did you find the solution for it yet? Thanks